# Assign HEAD to previous commit without losing the HEAD

Tags: git

I have a commit(A) in my local repository which I do not intend to push yet. Right now, the HEAD is at A. Let's say I want to create another commit(B) **NOT** on top of commit(A), but on top of the previous commit than commit(A).

**How do I assign my local HEAD to the previous commit without losing the latest commit(A)?**

I **DO NOT** want to undo/remove commit(A), I want to save it for later to rebase to the latest commit in my branch. After creating the commit B, I want to put commit(A) on top of commit(B).

Kind of like :-

C1 -> C2 -> A(HEAD)

to finally

C1 -> C2 -> B -> A(HEAD) (eventually)

How can I do this?

Edit :-
I have a restriction to do this without using another branch.

Comment: Why can't you use a temporary branch? Branches are cheap, and as long as you don't push the temporary branch, no one will know you used one.

Comment: I understand a restriction that would say you can't create a temporary branch on the server, to keep the server clean from temporary work, but the branches you create locally are only visible to you unless you push them.

Comment: Branches are just pointers to commits, and what you're asking for is how to keep a pointer to that A commit while you're working on another commit. The answer is, go ahead and create a pointer to it, i.e., a branch.

Comment: If "allowed" you could commit A -> B and then just switch the commit order by running `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, switch the two commit lines in the appearing editor and save+quit. Then you should end up with B -> A.

Comment: @joanis I apologize, I should have been more clear. I "want" to do this without using a "local" branch. To know other ways to do this.

Comment: There are bits of good practice-with-Git exercises in here, but the question as written is quite confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## With rebase

You could create a new commit now, then `rebase -i` to re-order them.

```
 (create B)
 git rebase -i head˜2
 (in the resulting pick list, re-order A and B)
 (Use `dd` and `P` to delete and paste lines)
 !wq // Exit vim
```

## With a temporary branch

```
 git checkout -b temp
 git reset --hard head˜1
 (create B)
 git cherry-pick A
 git checkout - // Checkout whatever your previous branch was
 git reset --hard temp
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is the answer that I want, but I am having trouble following your approach.  After the editor opens, it asks to re-order those commits but I can't even see the commit(B) I just created. Approach : "With rebase"

Comment: The newly-created commit will be the last in the list. The pick list is a list of commits to cherry-pick, so it will apply top-down oldest to newest. Perhaps you were expecting to see B at the top? If it's not there I can't think why :(

Answer (score 3):

From your branch,

```
# Save your branch with its commit A on a new branch
git branch backup_A

# Restore your branch one commit back
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

Your commit A will wait for you on the `backup_A` branch while you work on B.

When you're done with your commit B and want A on top, just cherry-pick it back :

```
git cherry-pick backup_A
```

Comment: I thought of this, but in my case I kind of have a restriction to do it with the same branch. I will add this info to the post.

Comment: @hitesh This **is** in the same branch. The `backup_A` branch is created but never cheched out. Everything above is to be executed on your branch. And the `backup_A` branch can be disposed of as soon as you've cherry-picked, with `git branch -D backup_A`